# Why does the ram not have the highest possible frequency?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have mounted a PC with the following motherboard and ram:

- [Tomahawk B350](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B350-TOMAHAWK.html#productFeature-section)
- [Corsair vengeance at 3000 MHz](http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/vengeance-lpx-16gb-2x8gb-ddr4-dram-3000mhz-c15-memory-kit-black-cmk16gx4m2b3000c15)

The motherboard can support frequencies up to 3200 MHz.

When I started the computer and went in the motherboard configuration, I saw that the RAM frequency was set at 2133 MHz. Change the frequency to 3000 MHz is considered as an overclocking.

Why is the default frequency so low?

Answer (score 2):

The [specs](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B350-TOMAHAWK.html#productSpecification-section) actually says so:

```
DDR4 Memory: 1866/ 2133/ 2400/ 2667(OC)/ 2933(OC)/ 3200(OC)+ Mhz
```

The "why"-question is speculation, but probably because the manufacturer can't (or won't) guarantee that the system is stable at 3200MHz.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not see the `OC` (this is the first computer I have built). This does not explain why it did not set it to 2133 instead of 2400.

Comment: Most MB's are conservative by default, and also only pay attention to the JEDEC SPD data on the memory module to determine operating parameters.  My guess is that the RAM in question has 2133 as it's highest configuration in the JEDEC SPD data, and has the higher settings listed in the XMP data.  Most good motherboards have an opion to use the XMP data instead.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn This is the answer I wanted. I searched in this direction, and it appears that I have to update the MB bios to have this option.